# How do I delete from database table data that is identical to the column of a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

My project has a datagridview with 3 columns that are completed manually by the user and a database table with 100 records

I need to delete from database table the records that are like the first column(Serial) of the datagridview

Serial | Lot | Date

89985 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03

89993 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03

90009 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03

90017 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03

90025 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03

```
for (int i = 0; i < dvgSeriiNoi.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Articol WHERE Serial = @Serial", con);
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial",
dvgSeriiNoi.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString());
  sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

with this code I managed to delete only the last (90025 | T2_4 | 2023-02-03) record

Comment: Use the debugger to see what values are getting passed.  Also use `var result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to see if the code worked.  If `result` is greater than zero, it worked.

Comment: using var result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); i try to delete 3 records from database for the first 2 the answer was 0 and for the last one was 1

Comment: Then those values don't match what's in the database.

Comment: I was entering data with copy paste in datagridview and I think it doesn't validate the cells